# How to remove null constraint for a column in Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

How to remove not null constraint for a column in Firebird 2.5?

Sadly, this didn't work:

```
Alter table ESTOQUE_GRUPO_SUBELEMENTO ALTER column ID_SUBELEMENTO  TYPE int  null  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebird 2.5, you cannot use DDL to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to an existing column, and dropping is only possible indirectly by dropping the constraint by name. This was changed in Firebird 3.0 (see [Manage Nullability in Domains and Columns](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-ddl-managenull) in the Firebird 3.0 release notes).

A `NOT NULL` is implemented as a constraint. If you named it (or lookup the generated name in the system tables), you can drop the constraint in Firebird 2.5. As documented in the *Firebird Null Guide*, section [Making non-nullable columns nullable again](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nullguide/firebird-null-guide.html#nullguide-make-column-nullable).

To drop it:

> ```sql
> alter table Adventures drop constraint IdNotNull
> ```

(where `IdNotNull` is the name of the `NOT NULL` constraint)

To find the name of a constraint, you can use the following query:

> ```sql
> select rc.rdb$constraint_name
> from rdb$relation_constraints rc
> inner join rdb$check_constraints cc
>   on rc.rdb$constraint_name = cc.rdb$constraint_name
> where rc.rdb$constraint_type = 'NOT NULL'
> and rc.rdb$relation_name = '<TableName>'
> and cc.rdb$trigger_name  = '<FieldName>'
> ```

See the link above for further details.

In Firebird 3.0 and higher, you can also use

```sql
alter table table_name alter column_name drop not null
```

Comment: Good, I was thinking about place some default value like 0 as an alternative. Glad it was possible to get rid of the not null constraint.